# NLP - amazon reviews feature extraction

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I'm working on the amazon reviews dataset.
the goal is to extract the positive and negative features of each product.

for example: for the sentence "this product has great battery life" I would like to extract the word 'battery' as a positive feature.

the dataset contains the fields:

**reviewerID** - ID of the reviewer, e.g. A2SUAM1J3GNN3B

**asin** - ID of the product, e.g. 0000013714

**reviewerName** - name of the reviewer

**helpful** - helpfulness rating of the review, e.g. 2/3

**reviewText** - text of the review

**overall** - rating of the product

**summary** - summary of the review

**unixReviewTime** - time of the review (unix time)

**reviewTime** - time of the review (raw)

So far I separated the reviews for two lists: positive_reviews and negative_reviews.

positive_reviews = all the reviews that have a rating > 3
, negative_reviews = all the reviews that have a rating < 3

I cleaned the text and tokenized it. after that, I extracted the nouns that came to after adjectives hoping that those specific nouns will be the features that I'm looking for.
after that, I tried to use clustering algorithms (k-means, DBSCAN) hoping that it will create a group that will represent the features I want to extract.

The results aren't good at all and I'm hoping that someone here might have an idea for a way for this to work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clustering, you might want to explore topic modelling; this will let you pull out the general themes from your reviews.

[Here's a guide](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/10/stepwise-guide-topic-modeling-latent-semantic-analysis/).

Comment: Hi @Peritract and thanks for the comment, I actually tried to use LDA for topic modeling but it was really slow and my computer couldn't handle it. 
I guess it because the dataset I'm using is really big.
I will try to follow the guide but just in case, maybe you have a suggestion for me to make it more efficient so it will run faster?

Comment: @As22 you could try using LDA Multicore - https://rare-technologies.com/multicore-lda-in-python-from-over-night-to-over-lunch/ - but it is always going to be relatively slow, just because of how complex it is with a large dataset.